# Performance testing using JMeter for dynamic 365 ecommerce website using ultimate thread group. How to increase concurrent sessions?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, dynamics-365

I am doing performance testing using JMeter for a 365 dynamics ecommerce website. Script is written and its working fine for following flow: Homepage> category listing> product detail page> add to cart> and complete checkout.

I want to run my script for 200 concurrent users with some time interval. Like, start with 30 concurrent sessions for 10 minutes then increase 60 users with total concurrent session 90 for next 10 minutes. Then increase 44 users with total concurrent session 134 for next 10 minutes, Then increase 66 more users with total concurrent session 200 for next 10 minutes.

I am using ultimate thread group for this but not sure how to set configuration. See attached image.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should amend your setup to introduce initial delay incrementing by 600 seconds for each group of new arrivals. The time to hold the load needs to be reduced by the same factor.

Example setup:

[image]

More information:

- [Ultimate Thread Group documentation](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/)
- [JMeter Ramp-Up - The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-the-ultimate-guide)

Comment: Hi @Dimitri, Don't you think startup time and shutdown time also need to be provided for this use case?

Comment: It's up to you, if you want user arrival/leaving to be more "smooth" you can add appropriate startup/shutdown times. The main idea of the ramp-up is that the load is increasing **gradually** so you could correlate increasing load with other [performance metrics](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420665-Performance-Metrics-for-Websites) like increasing throughput or response time. In your described scenario the load increases gradually already